# ASP.NET MVC Core Html.BeginForm() always links to first Action in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with the `Html.BeginForm()` function, where every time I press the `OkButton` submit in `_Prijava.cshtml`, it runs the `Prijava()` Action in the Controller.

This is the `LoginController.cs`:

```
namespace BumCoreWebAppMVC.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet] 
        [Route("/bum/Prijava.cshtml")]   
        public IActionResult Prijava()
        {
            var model = new LoginViewModel();
            return View("Prijava", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OkButton(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            //...
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view `Prijava.cshtml`

```
@model BumCoreWebAppMVC.Models.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewData["TitleHeader"] = "Prijava";
    Layout = "./BumLayout";
}
<!-- ... -->
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Login/_Prijava.cshtml", Model)
<!-- ... -->
```

This is the partial view `_Prijava.cshtml`

```
@model BumCoreWebAppMVC.Models.LoginViewModel
@{}
@using (Html.BeginForm("OkButton", "Login", FormMethod.Post)){
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.TextBox_ID, new {@class="form-control ", placeholder = "ID"})       
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

From what i've seen this should be work. I have a suspicion that maybe my `Program.cs` isn't correctly set:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseSession();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The strange thing is if I change the `OkButton()` Action to `[HttpGet]` and use `@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "OkButton", "Login")` it works just fine and it can find the correct Action. However the `Html.BeginForm("OkButton", "Login", FormMethod.Get)` will still not be able to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the most mind boggling solution.

It appears that the first `@using (Html.BeginForm())` will always call the wrong Action but the next ones will work correctly. So simply adding `@using (Html.BeginForm()){ }` at the top of the `_Prijava.cshtml` page will make the other ones work.

Comment: I was LOL when this actually did the trick!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not set the **Attribute Routing** in `RouteConfig.cs` file.

Inside **Solution Explorer** navigate to `App_Start` folder and open `RouteConfig.cs` file.

Add the following line bellow `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` line

```
routes.IgnoreRoute...;
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

**Final Step:** Don't use a trailing slash at the beginning of a `Route` attribute. Replace your route with this line

```
[Route("bum/Prijava.cshtml")]
```

[Demonstration Video](https://youtu.be/RRCFaYS2Z0c)

Comment: But there is no `App_Start` folder or a `RouteConfig.cs` file in the project.

Comment: @Graf123456 it is the mandatory file created when you first setup the project. Would you please attach solution explorer screenshot in question.